# Coverting unicode string to non unicode string in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement of inserting a hardcoded string value into table which is having column as varchar(100).

I have few more fields to insert that is coming from flat file and for inserting harcoded string I have used "Derived Column" component in SSIS.When I am mapping my derived column to varchar column in table ,I am getting an error "Cannot convert unicode to non-unicode string ".
I am wondering if there is any way I can convert this column to non-unicode string.

Please help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I solved the problem,in derived column component under expression we can give (DT_STR, 11, 1252) "String Name" and it will convert unicode to non-unicode string.

Comment: You can also use a Data Conversion transformation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can achieve this without explicit conversion by right clicking on the derived column component and selecting 'show advance editor'. 
Then 'Input and Output Properties' > 'Derived Column Output' > 'Output Column' > your column; then you can set the data type property to DT_STR.